# Why do I get an error when double quoting single quotes in a script that launches a remote SSH command?

Tags: shell-script, ssh, quoting

I have this script:

```
port=$1
cmd=$2
ssh root@127.0.0.1 -p $port "'"$cmd"'"
```

When running `myscript.sh 1000 "ls /dev/shm"` it get this error:

```
bash: ls /dev/shm: No such file or directory
```

In the script, if I echo the command (to see how it's evaluated) like this:

```
echo ssh root@127.0.0.1 -p $port "'"$cmd"'"
```

I get this:

```
echo ssh root@127.0.0.1 -p $port "'"$cmd"'"
```

Which is the proper command... So what is it that I am missing here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Just found out how to fix the problem so here is the guide:*

**How to troubleshoot commands that wont execute properly from within a script**

aka

**How to view exactly what is being executed by the shell**

In the script, enclose your problematic command with the set command:

```
set -x #unhide debug info
your command
set +x #hide debug info
```

In my previous example, were `port=1000` and `cmd="ls /dev/shm"`:

```
ssh root@127.0.0.1 -p $port "'"$cmd"'"
```

Was actually sent to the shell and executed as:

```
ssh root@127.0.0.1 -p 1000 ''\''ls' '/dev/shm'\'''
```

Look at that! Now we all know, double quotes " " are in fact an hyperactive bipolar single quote in disguise just waiting around the corner to mess with you... and sometimes it brings a friend called Mr. backslash.

The solution was to use double quotes in the script:

```
ssh root@127.0.0.1 -p $port "$cmd"
```

When combined with the double quotes from the command line the quoting get translated and executed as single quotes ' ' like this:

```
ssh root@127.0.0.1 -p 1000 'ls /dev/shm'
```

Who knew! you did? good for you!

Just another way nix messes with us :P