# How to execute grep command with multiple argument?

Tags: linux, shell-script, grep

I need to grep some data from other hosts, but i can't able to get here and store as variable. below are the commands which was I facing. Please suggest me.

```
DATE="2019-12-19 12:32:11"
LOG_FILE="/tmp/my_log"

ssh my_host grep -oPz "(?s)$DATE.*" $LOG_FILE | grep -i ERROR

bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: You are missing the pipe `|`?

Comment: Where @guillermochamorro

Comment: `ssh my_host | grep`

Comment: Related questions are of course https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4770/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/212215/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/518768/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/521613/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/157086/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/414636/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/347556/5132 , and many others.

Comment: Let me try @guillermochamorro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do :

```
DATE="2019-12-19 12:32:11"
LOG_FILE="/tmp/my_log"

ssh my_host <<EOF
grep -oPz "(?s)$DATE.*" $LOG_FILE | grep -i ERROR
EOF
```